# Multiprocessing: Instantiate Processes individually

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have an embarrassingly parallel problem in a Reinforcement-Learning context. I would like to let the neural network generate data in parallel. To achieve that each process needs its own model.

I have tried to use Pool to achieve this, but now I am not sure if this is the correct method.

```python
from multiprocessing import Pool

def run():
    with Pool(processes=8) as p:
        result = p.map_async(f, range(8))
        p.close()
        p.join()
        print(result.get())


def f(x):
    return x*x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I know that you can use an initializer to set up the processes, but I think this is used to set up the processes with the same fixed data.

```python
model = None

def worker_init():
    global model
    model = CNN()
```

This does not work. So how can I give every Process its own model?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "This does not work"?

Comment: Exactly what it says. It does not work. The initializer will give every process the same instance. I tried printing out the model for every process and it always had the same adress. I want every process to have its own instance.

Comment: I can tell you that it will work, so what makes you say it doesn't work ?

Comment: Why are the adresses of all the models the same then?

Comment: Any two objects in the same process should have different ids, different processes can have the same id, this doesn't mean they are in the same location in memory.

Comment: You should read about the difference between a Physical address space and a virtual address space.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. But is the global variable how I am supposed to do it? It feels like a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you are creating different objects, they just have the same id because the have the same virtual address, but the proper way to create individual workers that have their own "storage" is by subclassing [multiprocessing.Process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) instead of using global variables.

a pool is more about doing heterogenous memory-less work to a certain degree, or limiting the amount of work that is submitted at one time.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import random
class CNN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = random.randint(0, 100)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)
class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, identification, return_queue: Queue):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self.id = identification
        self.model = None
        self.return_queue = return_queue

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.model = CNN()
        self.return_queue.put((self.id, self.model))

def run():
    return_queue = Queue()
    workers = []
    for i in range(8):
        worker = Worker(i, return_queue)
        worker.start()
        workers.append(worker)
    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()
    while not return_queue.empty():
        res = return_queue.get()
        print("id =", res[0], ", content =", res[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

```
id = 0 , content = 72
id = 2 , content = 0
id = 1 , content = 95
id = 4 , content = 51
id = 5 , content = 83
id = 6 , content = 91
id = 3 , content = 7
id = 7 , content = 78
```

you don't really need to join them all before processing results if you know how much items you are expecting in the queue, you can poll the queue for exactly that number of returns and skip the joining part, you can also spin an asyncio loop to both wait for process end and poll the queue at the same time, the posted code is only the safest one in case the process crashed, without having to run an asyncio eventloop.